# C# Custom Sort String IComparer

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I want to change the sorting of strings so it is based off the following alphabet:

A,E,I,O,U,F,G,L,M,N,P,S,T,V,H,K,R

Instead of the standard A,B,C,D ... X,Y,Z

So I started to try and create a IComparer but stuck on how to implement.

Here is what I got so far which ain't much.

```
public class CustomSort : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @xanatos It would appear SamoanProgrammer's instructor has done the former and SP is trying to do the latter. :roll:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something very like this:

In the end you compare character by character, finding the "index" of the character inside a `Order` string. Perhaps to speed it up you could convert the `Order` string to a `Dictionary<char, int>` where the `int` is the "weight".

```
public class CustomSort : IComparer<string>
{
    public const string Order = "AEIOUFGLMNPSTVHKR";

    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            return b == null ? 0 : -1;
        }

        if (b == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        int minLength = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
        {
            int i1 = Order.IndexOf(a[i]);
            int i2 = Order.IndexOf(b[i]);

            if (i1 == -1)
            {
                throw new Exception(a);
            }

            if (i2 == -1)
            {
                throw new Exception(b);
            }

            int cmp = i1.CompareTo(i2);

            if (cmp != 0)
            {
                return cmp;
            }
        }

        return a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi xanatos, thank you very much. That has done exactly what I needed to do :) Awesome work mate!

Comment: So comparing "Hello There" to "HelloWorld" is going to thrown an exception, but comparing "Hello There" and "Hello" will not.

Comment: @juharr Yep :-) I don't do a correctness check on the whole string.

Comment: Actually both throw since you only deal with upper case characters.  I guess as long as the strings only contain upper case A-Z this is good enough, but should be noted.

Comment: Yeah, I found I got an exception with lower case characters but I fixed that up and spaces, but the bulk of what I needed done was handled as I wanted :)

Comment: @SamoanProgrammer What juharr meant is different: if you have "@" vs "A" then the method will throw on the "@"... But if you have "A@" vs "A" (or "B@" vs "A") then it won't throw, because only the first character will be compared, found equal, and then the comparison will be made on the length. The method will stop checking the correctness of the string on the first non-equal character, or at the end of the shortest string.

Comment: @SamoanProgrammer If you want to consider upper and lower to be the same, do `Order.IndexOf(a[i].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` and `Order.IndexOf(b[i].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, if you want to have all the upper < all the lower, then `"AEIOUFGLMNPSTVHKRaeioufglmnpstvhkr"`